Make navigations to the next View after pushing ATT message
enter image description here
Is it possible to make it automatic to go to the next View after answering App Tracking Transparency Dialog allert?

Black View with App Tracking Transparency Dialog on it
then user answer App Tracking Transparency  alert

After he answer - App automaticaly navigate to the next screen


